# Pandas Reading and arranging data in a text file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am new to this site and even to Python3. I am implementing something in Python3 as a hobby. I am getting some data on raspberry pi from different nodes and I am storing it in list format as ['Time', Id, value, Id, value,...] in a text file. I want to convert this data in a csv format using pandas. So while converting 
 to csv, in pandas dataframe, index is Time data from the list, columns are the Id data from list and values are stored in the cell against [Time, Id]. So one row with Time can have multiple values under the different Id columns. I have written this code to achieve it.

```
strtime = []
with open(filename, 'r') as feed:
   # loop through the lines
    for Line in feed:
        strtime.append(Line.split()[0][1:-1]) # capture the time
strtime = list(set(strtime))
strtime.sort()

df = pd.DataFrame(np.full((len(strtime), len(Id)), np.nan), columns = Ids, index = strtime)
with open(txtfile, 'r') as feed:
   # loop through the lines
    for Line in feed:
        # find which row to fill
        for jj in range(0, len(df.index)):
            if Line.split()[0][1:-1] == df.index[jj]:
                break              
        # j is the row number that needs to be filled 
        LocalCount = 0
        #find which column (s) to fill       
        for x in range(1, len(Line.split())): #get only the IDs
            if x % 2:
                Sig_ID = Line.split()[x][0:-1]
            else:
                Sig_val = Line.split()[x][0:-1]
            LocalCount+=1
            if LocalCount == 2:
                LocalCount = 0                
                #get id name from ID
                tempVal=int(float(Id))
                df.iloc[jj, tempVal] = value
```

The code seems to work and do the right thing. It genrates output like this:

```
             Id1    Id2 Id3 Id4 Id5
'15_38_20'  13.375  0           
'15_38_21'  13.375  0           
'15_38_22'  13.5                
'15_38_23'  13.5    0   0   0   
'15_38_24'  13.5    0           
'15_38_25'  13.5    0   0   0   
'15_38_26'  13.5    0           
'15_38_27'  13.375  0           
'15_38_28'  13.5    0           
'15_38_29'  13.5    0   0   0   
'15_38_30'  13.5    0
```

But if the txt file gets bigger in size the code seems to generate the csv slowly. I want to speed up the process. Is there any way I can speed up the process?

Comment: Appending into a dataframe is a slow process. Instead can't you write directly into a csv file?

Comment: I am thinking writing to a csv will take time. Because every second I am getting values from 6 different sources and I will have to check if it matches the previous time and then go and write it to the respective cell. Which will take time...isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is slow because you do everything with `for` loops, when Pandas can vectorize these operations.  The best example is this bit of code:

```
    # find which row to fill
    for jj in range(0, len(df.index)):
        if Line.split()[0][1:-1] == df.index[jj]:
            break
    # j is the row number that needs to be filled
```

That's slow.  This is fast:

```
    row = df.loc[Line.split(1)[0][1:-1]]
```

We only need to split `Line` into at most two parts (so `split(1)`), which saves allocations and garbage collection.  And we only do the split once, not in a `for` loop.  Finally, we use Pandas indexing to directly look up the value, rather than linear search.